# Formatting List Forms section Using JSON In SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have formatted SharePoint online list form by using JSON. Now how can I set background color of whole selection or section heading like green or Red, for example Approval section background color should be Maroon.

[image]

Comment: Hi @SPDev, Does below response answer your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, changing background color for section is *not possible* using JSON formatting capabilities.

Body configuration does not support advance JSON customizations like header/footer (or column/view formatting in list views).

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)